# Android: Overriding the scrollbar drawable in an application

Tags: android, scrollbar, drawable

Is there a way to replace the scrollbar drawable in an application (i.e. I have a customized scrollbar view that I would like to use instead of the default gray scrollbar that comes with the Android framework).  I looked through I believe all of the android attributes and none seem to support it (at least the simplest way I know how which I would assume would be setting a drawable to some android attribute).

If not and say it requires a change in the framework, where would I start looking for it (in the framework)?

Thanks

MB

Answer (score 9):

Custom scrollbar thumb:

```
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="..."
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="..."
```

Custom scrollbar track (scrollbar background):

```
android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="..."
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="..."
```